# looping option element with value from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

first of all,here's my code :

**views :**

```
function admin_add_menu(e)
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('vendors/ajax_admin_menu/')?>",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {id: e},
        success:function  (data) {
            $("#kategori_admin").html("<option>" + data[0]['nama'] + "</option>")
        }
    });


}
```

**admin controllers :**

```
public function ajax_admin_menu()
{   
    $ido = $this->input->post('id');
    $data = $this->person->get_adminby_id($ido);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**models:**

```
      public function get_adminby_id($id)
    {   
        $this->db->select('parentID,nama');
        $this->db->from('parentMenu');
        $this->db->where('outletID',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

i have web dashboard and i try to get data with jquery ajax,and as result i get json format array data,case in point,i want to combine the value with option and append it into select,and then looping it ( if there's multiple data like array ),sorry if this kinda silly question but,is that possible ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **model** change just one line.

```
public function get_adminby_id($id)
{   
    $this->db->select('parentID,nama');
    $this->db->from('parentMenu');
    $this->db->where('outletID',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

In **admin controller** change your code like this.

```
public function ajax_admin_menu()
{   
    $data = $this->person->get_adminby_id($ido);
    $option = "";
    if($data != array()){

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $option .= "<option value='".$value['parentID']."'>".$value['nama']."</option>"; 
        }

    }
    echo $option; exit;
}
```

In your **view** file

```
function admin_add_menu(e)
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('vendors/ajax_admin_menu/')?>",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data: {id: e},
        success:function  (data) {
            $("#kategori_admin").html(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Wow thank you soo much,it works,first i am kinda confuse,but then turns out it really works !

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

```
$ido = $this->input->post('id');
$data = $this->person->get_adminby_id($ido);
foreach($data as $row){
    echo $option .= "<option>".$row[0]->nama."</option>";
}
```

You need not have to use JSON parse as given in the Kumar Praveen's answer. Directly add the data to the HTML element.

```
$("#kategori_admin").html(data);
```

Hope you will get help out of this.

Comment: yes,i kinda confuse at first but then i understand that i have to iterate the option in the contoller,not in the view,really,thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Can your parse the response data using

```
var data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$("#kategori_admin").html("<option>" + data.name + "</option>");
```

try it if it works.

Comment: thanks for the reply,but can you explain it in detail,because i try it like this : var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data); and try to run it in console,the result is error

Comment: have you checked response in your console . go to network and check the what is the format of response.

Comment: yes,but even when i trigger it,ends up with error,so i follow naim code,but really thanks for the help